# Ruby on rails: Render 2 partials or figure out the kind of class and object is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display different types of objects in the same ajax called controller function. I want to render out when I send back an ajax call. The problem is I want the "title" attribute of one object and the "name" attribute of another object. I can't render 2 partials and can seem to figure out how to check the type of object an object is. How do I solve this problem?

Here is my current controller setup (NOT CORRECT)

```
@objects =  Obj.find(:all,:conditions => ["name Like ?", "#{prefix}%"])
@moreObjects = ObjTwo.find(:all,:conditions => ["title Like ?","#{prefix}%"])

if @objects.empty?
  render :text => "No Matches"
else
  render :partial => 'one', :collection => @objects
end

if  @moreObjects.empty?
  render :text => "No Matches"
else
  render :partial => 'two', :collection => @moreObjects
end
```

Comment: What do the partials "one" and "two" look like?  Are they pretty similar except for the name vs. title thing, or are there other points of differentiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
<%= obj.title if obj.respond_to?(:title) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option that doesn't involve checking its type - in your Obj and ObjTwo classes add a new method:

```
def fancy_pants
  title
end

def fancy_pants
  name
end
```

Then you can combine `@objects` and `@moreObjects` - you'll only need one if statement and one partial.

```
@search_domination = @objects + @moreObjects

if @search_domination.empty?
  render :text => "No Matches"
else
  render :partial => 'one', :collection => @search_domination
end
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing up something almost exactly like this answer.  Thus, +1.

Comment: Thanks Greg - Is there something you would have done differently? (besides wacky names) I'm always looking for new perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Object.is_a?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/is_a%3F) but that's not a very clean solution. You could also try mapping your data before presentation to help keep your views lightweight.

Comment: is_a? is at least in principal a bad practice in Ruby. Heard about duck typing?

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree. There are much better solutions. Just answering the question about object type checking posed above.